# C - Vector (Buscar la posicion del minimo del Vector 1 - Mostrar por pantalla los numeros pares e impares del Vector1)

Tags: c

Necesito

1.Mostrar por pantalla los numeros pares e impares del Vector1

2.Mostrar por pantalla el número mínimo del vector 1, y en qué posición del 
vector esta cada número. Por ejemplo: **El numero mínimo es el -3 que está en la posición 3**

Soy principiante en C, lo intente pero estoy mareado. Necesito ayuda de ustedes.
Aca les dejo mi codigo:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int largovector=0;
    int vector1[largovector];
    int vector2[largovector];
    int minimo=999999;
    int maximo=-999999;
    int contador=1;

    printf("Ingrese el largo del vector\n"); //Definimos el largo del vector
    scanf("%d",&largovector);

    for(j=1; j<=largovector; j++) //Definimos los numeros del vector
    {
        printf ("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada %d del vector: \n",j);
        scanf ("%d",&vector1[j]);
    }

    for(i=largovector; i>=0; i--,contador++) //Asignar los valores del vector1 al  vector2
    {
        vector2[contador]=vector1[i];
    }
    printf("El vector 1 esta formado por los numeros: ");//Imprimimos el primer vector

    for(j=1; j<=largovector; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",vector1[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("El vector 2 esta formado por los numeros: "); //Imprimimos el segundo vector

    for (i=1; i<=largovector; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",vector2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nCantidad de numeros pares en el vector: ");//imprimimos el par

    for(j=1; j<=largovector; j++)
    {
        int pares=j%2;
        if(pares==0)
            printf("%d ",j);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Cantidad de numeros impares en el vector: ");//imprimimos el impar
    for (j=1; j<=largovector; j++)
    {
        int impares=j%2;
        if(impares!=0)
            printf("%d ",j);
    }
    printf("\n");


    for (j=1; j<=largovector; j++)
    {
        if (j<=minimo)
            minimo = j;
    }

    printf("\nEl numero minimo es el %d que esta en la posicion %d",minimo);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes recordar que los índices para los arrays comienzan en **0**, es decir, si definís un array de 5 elementos, las posiciones son [0,1,2,3,4]. Ahora, cuando te piden que muestres los número pares e impares, se refieren a los elementos del vector 1, es decir, debes trabajar sobre los valores que tienes en el vector. Por lo que ví en tu código, estás trabajando sobre el índice para recorrer el vector y no sobre el elemento que es apuntado por ese índice:

Tu código (con la modificación de la dimensión):

```
for(j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        int pares=j%2;
        if(pares==0)
            printf("%d ",j);
    }
```

Aquí, estás controlando que el valor del índice sea par, y no es lo que necesitas, si no el elemento del vector al cual apunta ese índice, es decir, `vector1[j]`. Por ejemplo:

```
for(j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        int pares=vector1[j]%2;
        if(pares==0){
            printf("Par: %d ",vector1[j]);
        }else{printf("Impar: %d ",vector1[j]);}
    }
```

con esto se recorre el vector con el índice `j` y se controla si el elemento apuntado es par o impar, y se imprimen en cada caso.

Por otro lado, cuando buscás el menor elemento del vector, estás cometiendo el mismo error de trabajar con el índice y no con el valor al cual apunta ese índice:

Tu código (con la modificación de la dimensión):

```
for (j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        if (j<=minimo)
            minimo = j;
    }
```

Para este problema, tenés que recorrer el vector y buscar el menor elemento, cuando lo encontras tienes que guardar su posición también. Por ejemplo:

```
for (j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        if (vector1[j]<=minimo){
            minimo = vector1[j];
            pos = j;}
    }
```

si te fijás en `minimo` se guarda el elemento menor (`vector1[j]`) y no el valor del índice. También se guarda el valor de la posición donde está ese elemento, es decir, el valor del índice (`j`) en la variable `pos`.

Con esto revisado, el ejercicio podría quedar así:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int largovector ;

    int minimo=999999;
    int maximo=-999999;
    int contador=1;
    int pos=0;

    printf("Ingrese el largo del vector\n"); //Definimos el largo del vector
    scanf("%d",&largovector);

    int vector1[largovector];
    int vector2[largovector];
    printf("%d\n", largovector);
    for(j=0; j<largovector; j++) //Definimos los numeros del vector
    {
        printf ("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada %d del vector: \n",j);
        scanf ("%d",&vector1[j]);
        vector2[j] = vector1[j];
    }


    printf("El vector 1 esta formado por los numeros: ");//Imprimimos el primer vector

    for(j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",vector1[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("El vector 2 esta formado por los numeros: "); //Imprimimos el segundo vector

    for (i=0; i<largovector; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",vector2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nNum pares e impares del vector1: ");//imprimimos el par

    for(j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        int pares=vector1[j]%2;
        if(pares==0){
            printf("Par: %d ",vector1[j]);
        }else{printf("Impar: %d ",vector1[j]);}
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        if (vector1[j]<=minimo){
            minimo = vector1[j];
            pos = j+1;}
    }

    printf("\nEl numero minimo es el %d que esta en la posicion %d",minimo,pos);

    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
Ingrese el largo del vector
5
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada 1 del vector: 
10
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada 2 del vector: 
20
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada 3 del vector: 
15
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada 4 del vector: 
30
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada 5 del vector: 
50
El vector 1 esta formado por los numeros:  10  20  15  30  50 
El vector 2 esta formado por los numeros:  50  30  15  20  10 

Num pares e impares del vector1: Par: 10 Par: 20 Impar: 15 Par: 30 Par: 50 

El numero minimo es el 10 que esta en la posicion 1
```

Por último, para comenzar con `c` te recomiendo el libro "*El lenguaje de programación C*" de Brian Kernighan y Dennis Ritchie.